# アプリ起動時に StoryBoard 読み込みでクラッシュ

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

実機 (iOS 11.3) でアプリ起動時にクラッシュするのですが、原因が分からず困っています。
（シミュレーターではクラッシュしませんでした。）

クラッシュログの Backtrace に `[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:bundle:]` とあるので、
おそらく StoryBoard の読み込みでクラッシュしているのだと思うのですが、
StoryBoard のコネクションをチェックしても問題が見つかりませんでした。

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x1837e2d8c __exceptionPreprocess + 228
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x18299c5ec objc_exception_throw + 55
2   UIKit                               0x18dd31728 +[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:bundle:] + 783
3   UIKit                               0x18d793fb8 -[UIApplication _loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:] + 91
4   UIKit                               0x18d3b1254 -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 275
5   UIKit                               0x18d37f550 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1411
6   UIKit                               0x18d9afa0c __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 783
7   UIKit                               0x18d37ee4c +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 159
8   UIKit                               0x18d37ece8 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 239
9   UIKit                               0x18d37db78 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 723
10  UIKit                               0x18e01372c __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 295
11  UIKit                               0x18d37d268 -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 431
12  UIKit                               0x18ddf89b8 __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 219
13  UIKit                               0x18df46ae8 _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 111
14  UIKit                               0x18d37cc88 -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 247
15  UIKit                               0x18d37c624 -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 367
16  UIKit                               0x18d37965c -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 539
17  UIKit                               0x18d3793ac -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 363
18  FrontBoardServices                  0x185fe0470 -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 363
19  FrontBoardServices                  0x185fe8d6c __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 223
20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x1830d4ae4 _dispatch_client_callout + 15
21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x1830dc1f4 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 223
22  FrontBoardServices                  0x186014878 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 35
23  FrontBoardServices                  0x18601451c -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 403
24  FrontBoardServices                  0x186014ab8 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 55
25  CoreFoundation                      0x18378b404 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 23
26  CoreFoundation                      0x18378ac2c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 275
27  CoreFoundation                      0x18378879c __CFRunLoopRun + 1203
28  CoreFoundation                      0x1836a8da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 551
29  GraphicsServices                    0x18568b020 GSEventRunModal + 99
30  UIKit                               0x18d68978c UIApplicationMain + 235
31  xxxxxxxxxxx                         0x1004989c0 main + 35264 (SearchViewController.swift:16)
32  libdyld.dylib                       0x183139fc0 start + 3
```

また `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` で `callStackSymbols` しても、何も出力されませんでした。

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler { exception in print(exception.callStackSymbols) }
    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler { exception in print(exception.callStackSymbols) }
    return true
}
```

他に何かクラッシュの原因を探る方法はありますでしょうか？
何卒よろしくお願いします。

開発環境： Xcode 9.3
開発言語： Swift 4
実行環境： iOS 11.3 （実機）

Comment: もう少し情報が欲しいですね。そのクラッシュは実機での起動時に必ず起こるのでしょうか。スタックトレースはもっと深くまで見てください。デバッグコンソールには何もエラー情報は表示されないのでしょうか。Exception Breakpointは試されましたか。何か情報が追加されたらもう少し具体的なアドバイスもできるかもしれません。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/121828

Comment: OOPer さん、ご返信ありがとうございます。情報が不足しており申し訳ありません。実機では起動時に必ずクラッシュし、デバッグコンソールには libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException と表示されます。 Exception Breakpoint も試しましたが、 AppDelegate の最初で止まるだけで、クラッシュ原因の特定には至りませんでした。

Comment: **スタックトレースは底までチェック(提示)してください** 今回は起動時のクラッシュなので微妙ですが、通常クラッシュではそんな浅いところには真の原因はありません。 **Exception Breakpoint** では、発生位置の特定以外に`po $arg1`などで、コンソール出力より詳しい例外情報が取得できる可能性があります。 **StoryBoard の読み込み** 時にクラッシュする原因はコネクションの接続不良だけではありません。そもそも指定されたStoryboardが見つからない、ターゲットデバイスには存在しないフォントを指定している、と言ったことでもクラッシュの可能性があります。今のStoryboardをリネームして保存しておいた上で、新しいStoryboardに初期ビューを0から構築していって、どんな設定を入れたら実機でエラーになるのか、なんてのを試していくてもあります。もう当然やったかもしれませんが、 **シミュレータ・実機ともクリーンビルド** は必ず試して見てください。

Comment: また、原因の特定に有用な情報は、コメントだけでなく、本文を「編集」して本文に書き加えてください。「編集」することによりアクティブリストの上位に来ますし、本文に書かれた方がより多くの読者に見てもらえることが期待できます。いずれにしても、必ず再現する上にシミュレータで動くなら必ず対応する手立ては見つかるはずです。(最終的に「iOSのバグを踏んでいた」なんて答えになる可能性もありますが。)予断を持たずに、いろいろな可能性に確実にチェックを入れながら、ありえない選択肢を潰していくようにしてください。

Comment: OOPer さん、色々とアドバイスありがとうございます。原因はよく分からないままなのですが、新しく Storybaord を作り直したらクラッシュしなくなりました。（多言語化が）

Comment: すみません、続きです。（多言語化が原因かも・・・と思っております）ご参考になればと、本文にスタックトレースを追記いたしました。 stack overflow の使い方も教えていただき、大変参考になりました。感謝いたします。

Comment: 残念ながらXcodeにはStoryboardの編集機能にバグがあるようで、編集画面でコネクション等に問題が無いように見えても、内部的には矛盾した状態になってしまっていると言う場合があるようです。追加していただいたスタックトレースにも怪しいところは見当たらないので、今回はStoryboardの異常だろうと思います。残念ながら私の知る限りではStoryboardを作り直すしか仕方ないです。(文字通りの「私の知る限り」なので、何か良い確認の仕方や対処方法をご存知の方がおられるかも知れません。)